# PHP Joomla 4. Как отлавливать исключения объекта работы с базой данных или как для этой цели модифицировать класс?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, исключения, joomla

Ранее был написан модуль, который умеет работать с Wordpress, Joomla и Bitrix, и который использует для подключения к БД драйвер, предусмотренный CMS.

Таким образом, при работе с любой CMS для использования указанной библиотеки требовалось для использования просто подключить класс библиотеки, и сразу можно использовать её методы, не важно какая CMS, то есть, кроссплатформенно.

Указанная библиотека при первом использовании создаёт таблицу в базе данных для хранения различных своих данных, при этом момент необходимости создания таблицы определялся в момент, когда при SELECT-запросе к несуществующей таблице срабатывало исключение.

После того, как Joomla обновилась (вышла какая то из 4-ых версий), метод `$db->query()` заменил на `$db->execute()`, это казалось бы не проблема - была дописана логика, определяющая, в зависимости от версии Joomla, какой метод использовать, при этом в в методе `execute` используется обработчик исключений от Joomla, который ловит ситуацию отсутствия таблицы в БД выдаёт HTML-страницу ошибки 500 и мой обработчик исключений не срабатывает - следовательно, таблица не создаётся.

Делать метод для Joomla, который на этапе начала работы с библиотекой создаст таблицу - такой себе вариант, поскольку с разными CMS с библиотекой нужно уже работать по-разному и просто бы избежать бы лишнего действия и обучения для потенциального пользователя библиотеки.

Проверять перед SQL SELECT-запросом наличие таблицы вариант так же не очень, потому что так то бы эту таблицу 1 раз создать и далее только использовать, то есть так получается запрос, который в более чем 99.99% случаев лишний, и его бы тоже избежать.

И как раз исключение для создания таблицы при её отсутствии решало эту проблему.

Рассматриваю вариант унаследовать свой класс, в котором будет метод `execute` и в котором не будет отлавливаться исключение и использовать его в своей библиотеке, при этом получается приличная часть кода переписывается для этой цели.

Может, есть какой то другой вариант? Например, может быть можно как-то переопределить механизм исключений Joomla 4, чтобы именно в  данном случаe он не сработал, а затем (после выполнения нужного запроса) вернуть настройки в исходное состояние?

Или может быть как-то SQL запрос можно модифицировать, чтобы из результата его выполнения было понятно, что таблицы не существует?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, в Битриксе например, так проверяется существование таблицы перед установкой модуля.

```
global $DB, $DBType, $APPLICATION;

$bDBInstall = !$DB->Query("SELECT 'x' FROM l_table_name WHERE 1 = 0", true);

if ($bDBInstall) {
    $this->errors = $DB->RunSQLBatch($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/local/modules/module_name/install/db/".$DBType."/install.sql");
}

if ($this->errors !== false) {
    $APPLICATION->ThrowException(implode("<br>", $this->errors));
    return false;
} else {
    RegisterModule($this->MODULE_ID);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: У меня для Joomla примерно так и было: try {$db = JFactory::getDBO();$q = "SELECT * FROM `#__" . self::$tableName . "` WHERE (`minipinstack` <= $intIp) and (`maxipinstack` >= $intIp)";$db->setQuery($q);$r = $db->query();} catch (Exception $e) {тут проверить исключение не по причине ли отсутствия таблицы если из за этого код по созданию таблицы}